# Jquery or php, how to get various images in a div to display randomly?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a bunch of images/thumbnails on this [page](http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/all/) and would like to be able to have them display them in a random order after a refresh, does anyone know how?

I am using wordpress for this site but this is not a gallery otherwise i could use it in the gallery settings.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jqShuffle plugin](http://benjaminsterling.com/jquery-jqshuffle/).

A good place to call it would be inside your `functions.js`, just before you call Masonry:

```
$('.rugsAll').jqShuffle();
```

Comment: NIce one, i'll check this one out!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it, whether you're using JavaScript or PHP (it doesn't matter which, though the implementation is slightly different).

Either a) make an array of all the images you want to rotate through, or b) use a naming scheme for all the images, like image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc. Then, in code, you either pick a random array element (using method A) or pick a random number and fit it into your naming scheme (using method B).

In JavaScript, the effect is achieved by putting a placeholder image in your HTML, then, on page load, changing the image `src` to your randomly-selected image's path.

In PHP, you would set the image `src` to your randomly-selected image path as the page is being generated; this is how I usually do it, though I haven't done it in WordPress specifically.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick reply, the images run on a database so I would have no control over what the names would be so thought that maybe I could randomly order the images by the random script select the p tag that wraps the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the images are loaded and saved on your site. In this PHP solution the images should be saved in an array `$images`

```
$images = array( 'path/image1.jpg', 'path/image2.jpg', /* ... */ );

for( $i = 0, $i <= count($images)-1, $i++){

     $n = rand( $i, count($images)-1 );

     // display image or something

     unset( $images[$n] );
     $images = array_merge( array(), $images );
}
```